# VBA userform query - return to start of userform

Tags: vba, userform

I have the following code in a simple userform.
If the test for the start date being earlier than the end date fails, I want to go back to the top of the userform so I can correct the date(s) before exiting the form.
Is this possible?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If Not IsDate(TextBox2.Text) Then
        Label1.Visible = True
        TextBox2.SelStart = 0
        TextBox2.SelStart = 9
        TextBox2.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Start date format must be eg 01-Jan-21"
        Me.Hide
        Me.Show vbModal
    ElseIf Not IsDate(TextBox3.Text) Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        TextBox3.SelStart = 0
        TextBox3.SelStart = 9
        TextBox3.SetFocus
        MsgBox "End date format must be eg 03-Apr-21"
        Me.Hide
        Me.Show vbModal
    End If
    If CDate(TextBox2.Value) >= CDate(TextBox3.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Start date must be earlier than endate"
    End If
    Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub userform_initialize()
    OptionButton2.Value = True
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `userform_initialize()` Sub looks like it would work, have you tried just calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Only insert in the ElseIf chain the dates compare expression something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If Not IsDate(TextBox2.Text) Then
        Label1.Visible = True
        TextBox2.SelStart = 0
        TextBox2.SelStart = 9
        TextBox2.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Start date format must be eg 01-Jan-21"
        'Me.Hide
        'Me.Show vbModal
    ElseIf Not IsDate(TextBox3.Text) Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        TextBox3.SelStart = 0
        TextBox3.SelStart = 9
        TextBox3.SetFocus
        MsgBox "End date format must be eg 03-Apr-21"
        'Me.Hide
        'Me.Show vbModal
     ElseIf CDate(TextBox2.Value) >= CDate(TextBox3.Value) Then
         MsgBox "Start date must be earlier than endate"
     Else
         Me.Hide
     End If
    'End If
    'Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub userform_initialize()
    'OptionButton2.Value = True
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The Userform will only hided when everything is ok.